# How do I document members in specific sections using Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-2.7, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm struggling to figure out how to place the documentation for specific members of my Python class in specific sections of my Sphinx documentation, ideally while auto-documenting the rest in another section.

I have a Python class

```
class MyClass(object):

    def funky(self, arg):
        """Some docs."""
        ...
```

defined in `my/module.py` which works as expected and I can document without issues using

```
***************************
MyModule - :mod:`my.module`
***************************

.. automodule:: my.module

.. autoclass:: MyClass
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

But when I try to get more control over the organization of my documentation I can't get things working. Specifically, I'd like to have some members documented in explicit sections (just one is shown here, but there would be several), with the rest auto-documented as a group.

But when I try this with, for example

```
***************************
MyModule - :mod:`my.module`
***************************

To document
===========

Things that are not yet documented.

.. automodule:: my.module

.. autoclass:: MyClass
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
   :exclude-members: funky

Funky things
------------

Some funky things.

.. automethod:: funky
```

I get

> WARNING: don't know which module to import for autodocumenting u'funky' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule" directive in the document, or giving an explicit module name)

but no variations of

```
.. currentmodule:: my.module
.. class:: MyClass

.. automethod:: funky
```

or

```
.. currentmodule:: my.module

   .. automethod:: funky
```

etc. get me anywhere.

How do I auto-document some members of my class in specific places in my Sphinx documentation?

Comment: Does `.. automethod:: MyClass.funky` or `.. automethod:: my.module.MyClass.funky` work?

Comment: @mzjn: The former does! I swear I tried all these things before. I have no idea why they didn't work before!

Comment: @mzjn: I see what was up. I was using `automethod` where I should have used `autoattribute` and mixing up `autofunction` with both. Also is there a way to avoid having the state the class name each time? `module::` and `class::` don't do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
.. currentmodule:: my.module

.. automethod:: MyClass.funky
```

You could skip `.. currentmodule::` and do it like this:

```
.. automethod:: my.module.MyClass.funky
```

A third option:

```
.. currentmodule:: my.module

.. autoclass:: MyClass   

   .. automethod:: funky
```